# Python while loops to find Sundays on first of the month

Tags: python, arrays, while-loop

I'm working on a solution to Problem 19 of Project Euler

https://projecteuler.net/problem=19

The goal is to find the number of Sundays that fell on the first of the month in the 20th century. I'm attempting to complete the problem using only loops (not using datetime).

Here is my code right now:

```
days  = []

yearCnt = 1900;
dayCnt = 1;

Jan = 31;
Mar = 31;
Apr = 30;
May = 31;
Jun = 30;
Jul = 31;
Aug = 31;
Sep = 30;
Oct = 31;
Nov = 30;
Dec = 31;

while yearCnt < 2001:
    if yearCnt == 1900:
        Feb = 28;
    elif yearCnt%4 == 0:
        Feb = 29;
    else:
        Feb = 28;
    days.append(1);
    while dayCnt < Jan:
        days.append(0);
        dayCnt += 1;
    dayCnt = 1;
    days.append(1);
    while dayCnt < Feb:
        days.append(0);
        dayCnt += 1;
    dayCnt = 1;
    days.append(1);
    while dayCnt < Mar:
        days.append(0);
        dayCnt += 1;
    dayCnt = 1;
    days.append(1);
    while dayCnt < Apr:
        days.append(0);
        dayCnt += 1;
    dayCnt = 1;
    days.append(1);
    while dayCnt < May:
        days.append(0);
        dayCnt += 1;
    dayCnt = 1;
    days.append(1);
    while dayCnt < Jun:
        days.append(0);
        dayCnt += 1;
    dayCnt = 1;
    days.append(1);
    while dayCnt < Jul:
        days.append(0);
        dayCnt += 1;
    dayCnt = 1;
    days.append(1);
    while dayCnt < Aug:
        days.append(0);
        dayCnt += 1;
    dayCnt = 1;
    days.append(1);
    while dayCnt < Sep:
        days.append(0);
        dayCnt += 1;
    dayCnt = 1;
    days.append(1);
    while dayCnt < Oct:
        days.append(0);
        dayCnt += 1;
    dayCnt = 1;
    days.append(1);
    while dayCnt < Nov:
        days.append(0);
        dayCnt += 1;
    dayCnt = 1;
    days.append(1);
    while dayCnt < Dec:
        days.append(0);
        dayCnt += 1;
    dayCnt = 1;
    yearCnt += 1;

sunCnt = 6;

while sunCnt <= len(days):
    days[sunCnt] += 1;
    sunCnt += 7;

print(days.count(2));
```

The idea is to create an array of all the days with the positions of the first of the month marked with 1s.  Then another while loop goes through that array and adds 1 to mark all the Sundays.  In theory, the number of 2s should mark the number of Sundays on the first of the month.

It currently gives the answer 173.  I know the answer is 171 but I'd like to find out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Have you independently tested your code for telling whether a year is with 29 days in February?

Comment: You are including both years 1900 as well as 2000. I think that only one belongs to the 20th century.

Comment: The 20th century starts at 1901 and ends at 2000 (both included)

Comment: @chapelo My mistake, testing it again now

Comment: @chapelo You were correct, that was my mistake

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem ^

Comment: @Luke not entirely, `1 Jan 1901 to 31 Dec 2000`, 2000 is included

Answer (score 0):

It works if you change the code to start counting at Jan 1st, 1901.  You just need to change the loop at the end that marks each of the Sundays.

```
sunCnt = 6;
# Skip the year 1900
# Adding 364 will get to 1901 without messing up the day of the week
sunCnt += 364;

while sunCnt <= len(days):
    days[sunCnt] += 1;
    sunCnt += 7;
```